# Access localhost from windows virtualbox is not working

Tags: internet-explorer, virtualbox

I have downloaded a windows 10 IE edge virtual machine from windows dev

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/

In my mac I run the virtual machine and on IE edge I try to access my localhost dev environment which is run on localhost:3000 on the address http://10.0.2.2:3000 but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with 127.0.0.1:3000 (standard localhost adress) ?

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your need.
You would like to access your host from your VM?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly then we likewise have this problem on Windows 10 x64.

On more than one Windows 10 PC we see that the VB Host-Only network adapter shows:

```
IPv4 Connectivity: No network access
IPv6 Connectivity: No network access
Media State      : Enabled
Packets sent     : 0
Packets received : 0
```

This remains static despite all "not Edge" browsers connecting successfully to the local virtual server via the Host-Only adapter.

An interesting thing - that I do not see in other browsers - is that Edge appears to be "Network aware". To illustrate what I mean:

- first connect to say www.google.com via Edge while on the page,
  disable your wireless network connection
- in Edge try to reload the page: you should now see a broken heart with "You're not connected"
  showing next to it.
- Now reconnect your wireless network and don't touch Edge

...you should see that the Google page automatically redisplays.

Now I do the same test in Edge using my local test site URL (the VB Host-Only Adapter is enabled for the duration of this test)

- When wireless is connected Edge displays "Hmm, we can't reach this page"
- With the wireless disconnected the "You're not connected" broken heart message is displayed
- all other browsers work 100%

My conclusion is that Edge is entirely ignoring the Virtual Box Host-Only network adapter because of its anomalistic behaviour.

For more information on this please see the following bug I have opened on Virtual Box

[VirtualBox Ticket #15565](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15565)

....I have yet to hear anything from them sadly.